# Conditional validation with annotation

Tags: java, jpa, annotations, openjpa

I am building an API to create a configuration item for my system. The API will receive one of the following bodies:

```
{
  configType: "FILE",
  settings: {
    type: "CSV",
    location: "/folder/file.csv"
  }
}
```

or

```
{
  configType: "LDAP",
  settings: {
    ou: "CN=Users,OU=domain,OU=com",
    attribute: "sAMaccountName"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the `settings` object is different. Today I have two endpoints:

```
@POST
@Path("/configurations/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createFileConfig(@Valid FileConfigBuilder config)
```

and

```
@POST
@Path("/configurations/ldap")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createLdapConfig(@Valid LdapConfigBuilder config)
```

My goal is to have one single endpoint (`POST /configurations`) that allows me to send any of the bodies above and validates them based on the `configType` property. I do not want to write the validation by myself. I am wondering if there is already an annotation with condition check.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base class for both config builders:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "configType")
@JsonSubTypes(
{
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = FileConfigBuilder.class, name = "FILE"),
    @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = LdapConfigBuilder.class, name = "LDAP"),
}
)
public class ConfigBuilder {

}
```

You make your two classes extend this base class (don't forget to provide the proper `@JsonCreator` on the constructors):

```
public final class FileConfigBuilder extends ConfigBuilder

public final class LdapConfigBuilder extends ConfigBuilder
```

And take that class in parameter in your endpoint:

```
@POST
@Path("/configurations/file")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createConfig(@Valid ConfigBuilder config)
```

Spring should find the correct implementation based on the `configType` you pass through, and so will validate the parameter accordingly.